# How should I organise my micro-services for to enable independent deployment via CloudFormation

Tags: architecture, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to develop an application that is made up of multiple components that I want to be able to deploy independently.

Each component may contain parts packaged into Docker containers deployed into ECS or just Lambda functions. There will be some shared infra eg. VPC/Subnets/ALB/Databases etc

I am just wondering how can I manage this. It appears the easiest is I put everything into 1 repo with 1 large SAM/Cloudformation template but that does not seem scalable.

I was thinking of having:

- 1 base stack defining API Gateway, ALB, ECS Cluster, Subnets & Security Groups
- Each app will then define its own ECR/ECS Tasks/Services to be attached to the ECS Cluster, define its own ALB Target Group. Or if its lambda functions configure itself to link up with API Gateway.

But starting to find this very challenging. I think when I deploy 1 part it will remove APIs from the other services in such a setup?

Whats the recommended way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same structure at work. Basically, we are having the bunch of micro-services application mixed in java and golang. Each service should have its own infra stack (e.g. ALB, API gateway config, task fargate, dynamodb tables, etc).

However, all services are only shared the same **VPC** and **ECS cluster**. These resources were created as part of platform provisioning. Going forward, they are unlikely to be changed or to be changed frequently. Moreover, the microservice code + infra can be updated frequently as it's in different cloudformation stack. One point worth noting is that we are having the git common modules to avoid infra duplication across microservices e.g. ALB, Blue-Green deployment, etc are more or less same across microservices.

Hope it helps.